# 2 формы загрузки, загрузка одновременно в двух с выводом прогрессбара

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```js
  input.onchange = e => {
       (xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()).responseType = 'json';
       xhr.descc = ms.el.querySelector('#descc');
       
       console.log(xhr.descc);
       
       xhr.upload.onprogress = e => {
           console.log(xhr.descc);
           console.log(100 - (Math.ceil(e.loaded / e.total * 100)));
       }
```

Попытался сделать так, мол в объект добавить переменную и присвоить ей блок...

В общем, на странице 2 формы, в 2 формах есть блок. Допустим это прогресс бар, пользователь одновременно или скажем начинает загрузку во вторую форму тогда когда первая загрузка в первой форме не завершена.

Вопрос в том, как лучше всего разделить 2 формы. Если в каждой форме по своему прогресс бару и идет одновременная загрузка в обоих. Для прогресс баров значения для обоих форм будут разные.

То есть, не присваивая id или еще что в html документе. Возможно для каждой формы добавлять, закреплять свои объекты так, чтобы при одновременной загрузке выводить значение прогресс бара к каждой свое.

Comment: Как вы себе представляете прогресс бар для загрузки форм? Ответа либо нет, либо он уже пришел... Не очень понятен ваш вопрос

Comment: Добавил в onprogress, выводит процент загрузки. Для каждой формы отдельно, как задать объект к каждой форме так, чтобы в дальнейшем присваивать данное значение к необходимому блоку?

Comment: Возможно что та делаю не так, возможно при объявлении xhr необходимо на данном этапе задать уникальную переменную с id

Comment: Если вы хотите в 2-х местах показывать 2 прогресса, то сделайте 2 переменных. Хотите. суммируйте их и выводите среднее(допустим)